# Content-disposition header field not understood by IE, but works with Chrome

Tags: java, encoding

I am able to see properly the file name in Chrome but not in IE getting the encoded format for filename

(e.g. `=?UTF-8?B?5qWt55WM5pSv5Ye6UERGXzIwMTUwMjEwMTEwNjIy?=`).

```
fileName = "=?UTF-8?B?" + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8") + "?=";
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a non-ascii filename in the file download box in browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149058/how-to-display-a-non-ascii-filename-in-the-file-download-box-in-browsers)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the inputs. we have tried your option but facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no nice cross browser solution for this.  I found the nicely named article [Test Cases for HTTP Content-Disposition header field (RFC 6266) and the Encodings defined in RFCs 2047, 2231 and 5987](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/) which summarises what different browsers support. Although I couldn't see anything on the base64 mechanism you're using.

There are many different variants, try using the URL encoding form, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attwithfn2231utf8. Example

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''foo-%c3%a4-%e2%82%ac.html
```

This claims better support, assuming you only want > IE8

```
FF22    pass
MSIE8   unsupported
MSIE9   pass
Opera   pass
Saf6    pass
Konq    pass
Chr25   pass
```

Depending on what version of IE you're hoping to support you may have to do some dirty USER_AGENT sniffing and send a header.

```
if (isUserAgentIe(requestHeaders)) {
   fileName = ...
} else {
   fileName = ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, i have added content disposition and stil facing the same issue

Comment: What exact version of Internet Explorer is causing the issue?

Comment: Hi Adam, i have tried all versions of IE and facing the same issue.