# Content disposition for Downloading file in c#

Tags: c#, download, header, ascii

I want to download a file with Japanese filename without change the originality. 
Here is the code which I am using for download a file:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
var contentDisposition = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + Uri.EscapeDataString("filename");
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = contentDisposition;

return await _s3.DownloadFileAsStream(S3Storage.FilesBucket, filename);
```

This will return the file with filenames:

> High Siera.pdf --> High Siera.pdf (Correct)
>
> 2018年　国内カレンダー年 --> 2018年%E3%80%80国内カレンダー年 (Wrong)

Japanese filename getting escaped and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You get encoded value which is transformed during http communication. You can decode value before using. I hope this helps you. (HttpUtility in System.Web package)

```
string decodedFileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(filename);

return await _s3.DownloadFileAsStream(S3Storage.FilesBucket, decodedFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. from s3 I got the file correctly. But downloaded filename only having the issue.  When giving attachment name in Content-Disposition, need to encode the Japanese name.

Comment: I delete my answer then :)

May you add your solution and then may you mark as solved?

Comment: No Adem, I am sticking full day with this. i tried your solution and then only i posted comment.
var contentDisposition = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileitem.filename);

 Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", contentDisposition);

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 0):

As per RFC 2045-

> Current [RFC 2045] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence
>   Content-Disposition filenames) to **US-ASCII**. We recognize the great
>   desirability of allowing arbitrary character sets in filenames, but it
>   is beyond the scope of this document to define the necessary
>   mechanisms.

And you are doing right in escaping the same with UTF8. Having escaped characters in the downloaded file is expectedin this case.

For more information please check the below discussions-

[How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http/6745788#6745788)

and Here -

[How to display a non-ascii filename in the file download box in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149058/how-to-display-a-non-ascii-filename-in-the-file-download-box-in-browsers)